# What does this quote mean?

Tags: quotes

"It seems to me we have trouble making sense of much that is happening in the world because we are too ready to accept without question that there are always sound reasons for the enmity directed at the U.S., when often it is the sense of failure and envy that inspires the enmity."

Comment: what do you think it means?

Comment: I don't know I'm not sure

Comment: Hello, Omar. Unless you have a specific word or phrase to ask about, this sort of question is off-topic. It is addressing what used to be called 'comprehension' in junior schools years ago, and the original may be erroneous or ambiguous in any case. // Here, the author is saying that failings of others (failures at home / envy) rather than just cause often give rise to hatred of the US, and this should be given more consideration.

Answer (score 1):

"<strike>It seems to me</strike> **I think that** we have trouble making sense of <strike>much that</strike> **what** is happening in the world because we are too ready to accept <strike>without question</strike> that there are always sound reasons for the <strike>enmity</strike> **hatred** directed at the U.S. **by people in other countries**, when often it is the sense of failure and envy **of those people** that inspires the <strike>enmity</strike> **hatred**."

Does that help?